# Grep and sort several unsorted things in several lines (in one document)

Tags: text-processing, grep, awk, regular-expression

I have a file with several unsorted things in one line which I want to put into a new file
This is an example of part of the file I have:

```
X1314448: SaMi|SM_g2554.t1 SaMi|SM_g5072.t1 Des|Des_g3808.t1 Dul|Dul_comp50786_c0_seq1-1 Nig|Nig_comp88811_c0_seq2-1 AB|AB0003DMP400018076_AB0003DMT400026495 Phy|Phy_comp35647_c0_seq1-1 SWtf|SW_g27807.t1 Tom|Solyc02g077050.2.1
X1314810: Des|Des_g33587.t1 Nig|Nig_comp84357_c0_seq1-1 AB|AB0003DMP400020961_AB0003DMT400030857 Phy|Phy_comp33112_c0_seq1-1 SaMi|SM_g27352.t1 SWtf|SW_g21774.t1 TAIR|AT4G14930.1 Tom|Solyc06g054250.2.1 Dul|Dul_comp63657_c0_seq2-1
X1327159: AB|AB0003DMP400016823_AB0003DMT400024599 AB|AB0003DMP400017933_AB0003DMT400026257 Dul|Dul_comp58749_c0_seq2-1

X1330513: Des|Des_g36886.t1 AB|AB0003DMP400049952_AB0003DMT400073802 SWtf|SW_g16502.t1

X132738: Des|Des_g491.t1 Des|Des_g6171.t1 Dul|Dul_comp57659_c0_seq2-1 Dul|Dul_comp57659_c0_seq3-1 Dul|Dul_comp57659_c0_seq4-1 Ni                                                                       g|Nig_comp93106_c3_seq1-1 Nig|Nig_comp93106_c3_seq2-1 AB|AB0003DMP400005485_AB0003DMT400007895 AB|AB0003DMP400021388_PGS                                                                       C0003DMT400031553 Phy|Phy_comp61931_c0_seq1-1 Phy|Phy_comp61931_c0_seq2-1 Phy|Phy_comp61931_c0_seq3-1 Phy|Phy_comp61931_c0_seq4-1                                                                        RICE|LOC_Os08g43334.1 RICE|LOC_Os08g43334.2 RICE|LOC_Os09g35790.1 RICE|LOC_Os09g35790.2 SaMi|SM_g30888.t1 SaMi|SM_g5888.t1 SWtf|SW                                                                       _g17547.t1 SWtf|SW_g33717.t1 Des|Des_g47565.t1 SaMi|SM_g6027.t1 SWtf|SW_g42019.t1 TAIR|AT5G62020.1 Tom|Solyc03g026020.2.1 TAIR|AT4                                                                       G11660.1
```

What I want is to have the first part, "X1314448:" followed by by "Des|Des_g3808.t1”. And if there is another “Des_xxx” (in some cases there are more than one, like in the second to last line), I want that to be included as well, followed by the “AB|AB00…” in the output file, but since it is an unsorted list I am uncertain how to sort out the three different parts I want while still keeping them on the same line (keeping them linked to each other). I am also not sure how to get several matches on one line like this.

So for the first line, the output should be:

```
X1314448: Des|Des_g3808.t1 AB|AB0003DMP400018076_AB0003DMT400026495
```

For the second to last last one:

```
X1330513: Des|Des_g36886.t1 AB|AB0003DMP400049952_AB0003DMT400073802
```

for the last one:

```
X132738: Des|Des_g491.t1 Des|Des_g6171.t1 Des|Des_g47565.t1 AB|AB0003DMP400005485_AB0003DMT400007895 AB|AB0003DMP400021388_PGSC0003DMT400031553
```

I think the main problem is the last line. I also want to be able to modify the file to
have the "Dul|..." included as well.

---

## Solution:

After working on it a bit I ended up with:
1 - Save this script as `FastaToTbl` and make it executable (`chmod 744 FastaToTbl`):

```
if (substr($1,1,1)==">")
       if (NR>1)
             printf "\n%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
      else
         printf "%s\t", substr($0,2,length($0)-1)
       else
          printf "%s", $0
}END{printf "\n"}'  "$@"
```

2 - make and a second file containing this script:
Use `FastaToTbl` combined with this script to extract the IDs from `file1` and the sequences from `file2`:

```
 ./mktbl file1[contains FASTA sequences] |
  perl -ne 'chomp;@a=split(/\t/); $k{$a[0]}=$a[1]; ## Collect the sequences
                                               ## $k{ID}=SEQUENCE
      END{open(A,"File02[contains my data that is missing FASTA sequences (ID file)]");   ## Open ID file
         while(<A>){         ## and process it line by line
           @a=split(/\s+/);  ## Gather the IDs in array @a
           print shift(@a);  ## Print the first element (Jan123:)
           print "$_ $k{$_}\n" for @a; ## Print each ID and its seq
 }}'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^ *$/ {next;}; NR>1 {print bufline;};
  {bufline=$1 " ";
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++)
      { if ($i ~ "^Des\\|" || $i ~ "^AB\\|") bufline=bufline sprintf("%s ",$i);
        if ($i ~ "^Dul\\|") dul=$i;
      };
  };
  END {print bufline " " dul;}' inputfile
```

Comment: After working on it a bit I ended up with a working solution! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Wouldn't this work for you:

```
sort -k 2
```

Basically, sort by default will define columns by white spaces, you can change this is option `-t`. In this case I'm letting it know to sort by the second field. And from a first look it gets what you want.

If you want to make consecutive sort, you can still use sort adding extra `-k` options.
Fromt the man page:

> ```
>    -k, --key=KEYDEF
>           sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
> ```
>
> KEYDEF  is  F[.C][OPTS][,F[.C][OPTS]]  for  start and stop position, where F is a field number and C a character position in the field; both are origin 1, and the stop position defaults to the line's end

```
X1327159: AB|AB0003DMP400016823_AB0003DMT400024599 AB|AB0003DMP400017933_AB0003DMT400026257 Dul|Dul_comp58749_c0_seq2-1
X1314810: Des|Des_g33587.t1 Nig|Nig_comp84357_c0_seq1-1 AB|AB0003DMP400020961_AB0003DMT400030857 Phy|Phy_comp33112_c0_seq1-1 SaMi|SM_g27352.t1 SWtf|SW_g21774.t1 TAIR|AT4G14930.1 Tom|Solyc06g054250.2.1 Dul|Dul_comp63657_c0_seq2-1
X1330513: Des|Des_g36886.t1 AB|AB0003DMP400049952_AB0003DMT400073802 SWtf|SW_g16502.t1
X132738: Des|Des_g491.t1 Des|Des_g6171.t1 Dul|Dul_comp57659_c0_seq2-1 Dul|Dul_comp57659_c0_seq3-1 Dul|Dul_comp57659_c0_seq4-1 Ni
```